Is there any way to solve such expressions
I want to solve this expression
// Java program

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 5;
        i += i++ + i-- + i--;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

The confusion arises from the order of operations. The output is 21 because the post-increment and post-decrement operations are evaluated after the current value of 'i' is used. Thus, 'i' is added to itself before the increments and decrements occur. This is why the result differs from the expected 19.

What is your question? Also, why did you tag this with C++?

You might consider using jshell and experimenting with the various pieces of that code. In Java it has well defined behavior, evaluates left to right and has side effects. In other languages, it's a classic example of undefined behavior. Personally, I can't think of any place where such obfuscated code would be appropriate to use.

@ndc85430 Check out this answer and see if it helps.
